# How do I get the value of this variable outside the .then((){}); statement in flutter?

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following lines of code

```
bool check;

Firestore.instance.collection('tests').where('name',isEqualTo: snapshot['name'].replaceAll('.mp4','.txt')).getDocuments().then((docs){
  if(docs.documents[0].exists) check = true;
  else check = false;
});
debugPrint(check.toString());
```

This produces an error saying that a bool can't have a value of null, so how do I retrieve the value of `check` from inside the `.then` statement so that I can use it outside of the `.then` statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the `.then()` clause you need to do all your work inside it and you can't use its values outside because you don't know when you are receiving the answer.

You could `await` the answer there and mark the method that encloses your code with `async`.

```
bool check;
final docs = Firestore.instance.collection('tests').where('name',isEqualTo: snapshot['name'].replaceAll('.mp4','.txt')).getDocuments();
if(docs.documents[0].exists)
  check = true;
else
  check = false;
debugPrint(check.toString());
```

or

```
Future<void> doSomething() async {
  bool check;
  final docs = Firestore.instance.collection('tests').where('name',isEqualTo: 
  snapshot['name'].replaceAll('.mp4','.txt')).getDocuments();
  if(docs.documents[0].exists)
    check = true;
  else
    check = false;
  debugPrint(check.toString());
}
```

Comment: why would `await` block UI thread? in dart there is only one, UI thread so any use of `await` would block it? it simply suspends the execution, and not blocks the whole thread

Comment: I have rephrased my answer. It is not possible to infer from your question where your code is located. If you can't use an `await` then you must use the `then()` but then you can't reliable access the variable inside from outside. `await` can be used without blocking the ui if the method call is marked with `async` and is used accordingly.

Comment: Could you provide more context to the question?

Comment: `await` and `then` are really the same things - and no, you cannot use `await` in a method that is not `async`

Comment: Telling that `await` and `then` are the same thing is a bit misleading. They are two different ways of handling the same asynchronous response. The end result is the same but through different paths.

Comment: i agree - different paths - but in any way, neither `await` nor `then` blocks UI thread as you wrote in your answer

Comment: Right. Async call don't block the ui per se. What I meant is that, depending on how and where you call your async methods with await, you could block the ui.

Comment: fortunately `await` will never block ui thread, see https://www.dartlang.org/articles/language/await-async or similar articles

Comment: I understand what you mean really mean but that is only true if you use await/async correctly. In the gist https://gist.github.com/jmolins/cd426981fa3f675aed55b035cb63d4b4 you can see that the ui is easily blocked with an incorrect call.

Comment: No, it does not block the UI. Try tapping the FAB multiple times. Each time you see the ink ripple, and after 4 seconds the counter increments N times. The UI is perfectly functional and responsive; you've just asked it to change the counter after 4 seconds - which it does.

Comment: Yes. You';re right. I see what you mean. The UI is not blocked. But depending on how you use the await, the UI may not be updated as you expect. At least in this case. Thanks for the patience.

Comment: as Richard said the UI is not blocked: think of `var x  = await future; print(x);` as: `future.then((x) => print(x));` - this is really the same code