# Flutter Stateful Widget initState() appears to stop processing after .get().then() from Firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Can anyone explain what is happening here?

After the code

```
if (widget.surveyId != "new") {
        model!.get().then((value) {
          try {
            survey = value.data()!;
          } catch (error) {
            print(error);
          }
        });
```

Nothing below the try catch blocks are executing when the surveyID != "new".  I have a lot of print statements trying to figure this out and nothing is throwing an error.

```
    _nameController.text = survey.name ?? '';
    _ssnController.text = survey.ssn ?? '';
    _dobController.text = survey.dob ?? '';
    _dobDate = survey.dobDT;
    _livingSituation = survey.livingSituation;
    _situationChoose = survey.livingSituation ?? livingSituationList[0];
    _onLivingSituationItemSelected(_livingSituation);
    _ageController.text = survey.age ?? '';
    print(jsonEncode(_livingSituation));
    print(jsonEncode(_situationChoose));
```

The code above works when I include it in the try block but I would like to keep it out of that if possible.

Full code of initState()

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _isLoading = true;
    surveyId = widget.surveyId != "new" ? widget.surveyId : null;
    _situationChoose = livingSituationList[0];
    _ssnFocusNode.addListener(_ssnOnFocusChange);
    _dobController.addListener(_ageCalculator);
    print('Survey ID: $surveyId');
    model = _firestore
        .collection('surveys')
        .doc(widget.surveyId == "new" ? null : widget.surveyId)
        .withConverter<SurveyItem>(fromFirestore: (snapshot, _) {
      print('from Firestore called');
      final data = snapshot.data();
      if (data != null) {
        return SurveyItem.fromMap(data);
      } else {
        print('data is null');
        return SurveyItem(); // or return a default SurveyItem object
      }
    }, toFirestore: (SurveyItem survey, _) {
      print('to Firestore called');
      return survey.toMap();
    });
    try {
      if (widget.surveyId != "new") {
        model!.get().then((value) {
          try {
            survey = value.data()!;
          } catch (error) {
            print(error);
          }
        });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
      if (mounted) {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).clearSnackBars();
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(
            content: const Text(
                'An error occured. Please try again later and check your internet connection.'),
            backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.error,
          ),
        );
      }
    }

    _nameController.text = survey.name ?? '';
    _ssnController.text = survey.ssn ?? '';
    _dobController.text = survey.dob ?? '';
    _dobDate = survey.dobDT;
    _livingSituation = survey.livingSituation;
    _situationChoose = survey.livingSituation ?? livingSituationList[0];
    _onLivingSituationItemSelected(_livingSituation);
    _ageController.text = survey.age ?? '';
    print(jsonEncode(_livingSituation));
    print(jsonEncode(_situationChoose));

    //print('_situationChoose: ${_situationChoose!.situationName}');
    _isLoading = false;
  }
```

I am expecting the initState() to continue procesing.  At the moment I have put the code in a seperate function but it is odd to me that at this point it stops.

Comment: initState is synchronous.  Launching something async in there guarantees that it will *not* complete until build() has run at least once with the former values. You need something like a FutureBuilder here.

Comment: Part of my problem is I was looking for print statements but what they were printing were null values and I also had some others that were intentionally printing null so I didn't think my print statements were getting executed but they in fact were.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53916529/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-this-variable-outside-the-then-statement-in-fl) shortly after posting this.  I was searching based on the initState() portion instead of the .get.then()